# Find sequence of choice in a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is a table where user_id is for each test taker, and choice is the answer for all the three questions. I would like to get all the different sequence of choices that test taker made and count the sequence. Is there a way to write sql query to achieve this? Thanks

```
----------------------------------
| user_id        | Choice        |      
----------------------------------
|     1          |   a           |
----------------------------------
|     1          |   b           |    
----------------------------------
|     1          |   c           |
----------------------------------
|     2          |   b           |
----------------------------------
|     2          |   c           |
----------------------------------    
|     2          |   a           |
----------------------------------
```

Desire answer:

```
----------------------------------    
|     choice          |  count   |
----------------------------------
|      a,b,c          |    1     |
----------------------------------
|      b,c,a          |    1      |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are really using -- that is, remove one of the database tags.

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you can use aggregation functions:

```
select choices, count(*)
from (select string_agg(choice order by ?) as choices, user_id
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) t
group by choices;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering of the table.  Remember:  tables represent *unordered* sets, so without such a column the choices can be in any order.

You can do something similar in SQL Server 2017+ using `string_agg()`.  In earlier versions, you have to use an XML method, which is rather unpleasant.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Just noticed that grouping by expression cannot be applied to array, but we can transform the array to Jason by using TO_JSON_STRING(choice)

Comment: @peteraa . . . I thought I had aggregated by arrays.  That must've been in Postgres.